# What is this type of sign called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

[image: board]
It's at the entrance to my apartment. What is this type/style of signage called?

Comment: It  is called  “sign.” - *A sign is a piece of wood, metal, or plastic with words or pictures on it. Signs give you information about something, or give you a warning or an instruction.*  Collins

Comment: While that's true, some signs have slightly more specific names, like "nameplate". (Although nameplates usually go on doors or desks; the pictured one is big.)

Comment: 'Nameboard' might be frowned on by principals as being too down-market. But it _is_ a board with a name on.

Comment: As per a quick Google search, these are often called *entrance signs* or *panel signs* or, as per @Laurel, *monument signs*. There doesn't seem to be any standardization. To complicate matters further, each of these types may include signs that serve different purposes. For example, *entrance signs* may be signs such as the OPs, signs on the doors entering facilities, signs near highway on-ramps, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The websites of some companies that sell similar signs (for example [one in California](https://superiorsignsandgraphics.com/products_services/apartment-complex-signage-orange-county/) and [one in Georgia](https://bigmouthsigns.com/exterior-signs/apartment-complex-signs/)) call them “apartment complex signs”. This makes it clear that it’s for the entire complex and not just a single apartment.

(In addition, this seems to be a “monument sign”.)

Comment: By "more specifically" I presume you mean "more generally"? ^_^

Comment: @Robusto “differently specifically” :p

Comment: More specific in the world of apartment complex signs; more general in the world of signs in general.